# Open Material UI accordion by location.hash

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I am trying to open the Accordion via the location.hash (this might be #panel-1)

I map through the categories, and then display via:

```
<Accordion elevation={1} defaultExpanded={false} className="filter-items-accordion" id={key.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}>
```

key is the category name that I assign as that accordion ID.

I understand the Accordion has an expanded state and while I may try something like:

```
expanded={expanded === key.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}
```

on the Accordion properties and then if I define:

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel-1');
```

I has that open, but I cannot open other accordions on the same page.

How do I open that specific accordion on the page, while being able to expand the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a React `useState` hook to store the expanded state of each accordion item, and then use a `useEffect` hook to listen for changes in the `location.hash` and update the state accordingly.

For example:

```
const toHash = (category) => {
  return category
    .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, "");
};

function App() {
  const categories = useRef([]);
  const keys = useRef([]);

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState({});

  const toggleExpanded = (key) => {
    setExpanded((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [key]: !prev[key]
    }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // instead of assigning constant, you can use API call.
    categories.current = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"];
    keys.current = categories.current.map(toHash);
    const hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    if (keys.current.includes(hash)) {
      setExpanded((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [hash]: true
      }));
    } else {
      setExpanded(
        keys.current.reduce((obj, key) => {
          obj[key] = false;
          return obj;
        }, {})
      );
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {keys.current.map((key, index) => (
        <Accordion
          key={key}
          id={key}
          expanded={expanded[key]}
          onChange={() => toggleExpanded(key)}
        >
          <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
            <Typography>{categories.current[index]}</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              <!-- Details -->
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-currying-85ksc7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for that. const keys = ["panel-1", "panel-2", "panel-3"]; ... what if you don't know the keys beforehand? ie. they key is based off the category which could be different for every user

Comment: @PaulVI, If so, I updated my answer. please check it